# how to do advanced filtering of database entity by their 'tag' attritube

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

have been bothered by this question for some time and really appreciate your advice

Suppose I have a db for personal blog here:

first table:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
pid TINYINT,
content TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (pid)
);
```

second table:

```
CREATE TABLE tags(
pid TINYINT,
tag VARCHAR(16),
PRIMARY KEY (pid, tag),
FOREIGN KEY (tag) REFERENCES posts(pid)
);
```

and say 
they have some data like

```
tags

------------------------------
pid             |          tag
1               |            a
1               |            b
1               |            d

2               |            a
2               |            c
```

and I'd like to allow client(user) to do 'advanced filtering'

like using `` SELECT pid FROM tags WHERE tag `MATCHES` a && ( b || c ) && !d `` to match exactly `pid` 2

Comment: Hard. Lots of joins. Discussion on [EAV topic on this link](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Comment: very interestingly, seems I have found by using UNION, INTERSECT and MINUS, we shall be able to at least demonstrate this in an easy way. just like `SELECT pid FROM tags WHERE tag ='a' INTERSECT (SELECT pid FROM tags WHERE tag='b' UNION SELECT pid FROM tags WHERE tag = 'c') INTERSECT ( ( SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM tags) MINUS  (SELECT pid FROM tags WHERE tag='d'))`. That is,` && -> INTERSECT, || -> UNION, ! -> ALL MINUS EQUAL $var`

Answer (score 0):

A rather straight-forward mapping of `WHERE tag`MATCHES`a && ( b || c ) && !d` is

```
WHERE     ( EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE pid = a.pid AND tag = 'a' )
  AND     ( EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE pid = a.pid AND tag IN ('b', 'c') )
  AND NOT ( EXISTS SELECT 1 FROM tags WHERE pid = a.pid AND tag = 'd' )
```

However, since it is multiple correlated subqueries, it will not scale well.  This may work adequately well up to a few thousand rows, but if you need millions, then we need to discuss more complex approaches.